# JSON (not jsonb column) column merge for multiple objects in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

Initially I have the JSON hash value like,
          a = { "1": 1, "2": 2 }. ( Initial json hash)

Now I need to add the new key-value pair to the json hash 
          { "3": 3 }.( New hash key-pair )

After merged the new value, My hash looks like
           a = { "1": 1, "2": 2,"3": 3 }. ( Result json hash )

```
Can you please share your logic for satisfying the above conditions for multiple objects?

 Note: 1. My column is not a jsonb. It's a json column. 
       2. I am using the postsgres database.
       3. Merge the key-value pair to multiple objects columns.
```

Comment: What is your PostgreSQL version?

Answer (score 0):

Thats simple. We can make use of ruby syntax `merge` to get the expected result.

```
a = { "1": 1, "2": 2 }
b = { "3": 3 }
result = a.merge(b) # will give you { "1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgres 9.5+, you can convert it to `jsonb` and concatenate it using || operator and then cast it to `json` type.

```
UPDATE t 
    SET    json_col = (json_col ::jsonb ||  '{ "3": 3 }' ::jsonb)::json;
```

For older versions, you may have to convert it to text combine and do some manipulations  to convert to `json` type.

```
UPDATE t 
    SET    json_col = ( replace(json_col :: text, '}', ',') 
            || replace('{ "3": 3 }', '{', '' ) ) :: json ;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3303686d4b38ce12df5007555d1a1b6b)